# Service Discovery with Vert.x gRPC and Consul

Tags: vert.x, grpc, consul

I have a service which runs a couple of verticles. The main verticle configures the remaining verticles and is also responsible for registering the service with consul. However, my gRPC server cannot run on the same port as the main verticle. Does this mean I need to register each verticle as a separate service, or is there some way to use consul to advertise the correct port for my gRPC server?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like tags are the way to go. I can't find the link to the github issue discussing single services with multiple ports, but that was the suggestion. Multiple ports is something being considered for a future API but there are obstacles such as the SRV entries to contend with before this is possible.